# users who flag this node also flag

Tags: views, flags

I created a flag named 'like', user can 'like' every node, and below down the node footer, show 'users who like this node also like'.

Just like Amazon's Customers Who Bought This Item Also Bought

[image]

I think the normally process is :

1. find users who flag this node.
2. loop every users, and find each user's flaged node.

But if 1000 people flag this node, it will be very slowly!

I think may Views module can do this. but i think it will slowly too.

Comment: Hi, I don't know why down-vote me. please comment me, I will update my question.

Comment: How are you storing the uid of the user who likes a node against that node? E.g. is there a field attached to the node that holds the uids?